# dojo: How to create two or more than two radio buttons in contentpane?

Tags: javascript, dojo, radio-button

I am really new to dojo. I have to create two or more that two Radio buttons using dojo content pane "Programmatic" not the "declarative".

I manage to make one radio button but how to make another one, well I am embarrassed, Here I done for one;

```
var radioButtonPane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
            splitter:true,
            region: "top",
            style: "background-color: white;width: 175px; height: 40px",
            content: "RadioButtons"                       
                });
var radioOne = new dijit.form.RadioButton({
            checked: true,
            value: "ProjectOne",
            name: "Project 1",
            }, "radioOne");


 //setting one radio button in content of contentpane, how add another one?
 radioButtonPane.set('content',radioOne);
```

I should not make a "div" for it,

I know its a very dumb question, Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why you shouldn't make a `div` for it? it's the easiest solution - to populate your `ContentPane` with divs, one for each radio button. In final html code it will be converted to `div`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I really know that creating with div is the easiest way but I have to do in programmatic way.

Comment: it's not a problem, have you heard about dojo.create?
 http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/create.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer in a proper form ; )

1. use [dojo.create](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/create.html) to create new `div` tag
2. insert your radio button in this new tag

Comment: Thank you, I just added my answer just to show that I did I solved it..I think this is the correct way, right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help as per @h4b0 user's comments

> " it's not a problem, have you heard about dojo.create? [dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/create.html](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/create.html)"

I replaced my code with this;

```
var radioOne = dojo.create("div", { 
    innerHTML:"<input type='radio' data-dojo-type='dijit.form.RadioButton' name='Project Cost' id='radioOne' value='Cost' checked: 'true'/>" + "<label for='radioOne'>Project Cost</label><br />" 
    + "<input type='radio' data-dojo-type='dijit.form.RadioButton' name='Project Statistics' id='radioTwo' value='Project_Statistics' checked: 'true'/>" + "<label for='radioOne'>Project Statistics</label><br />"
    + "<input type='radio' data-dojo-type='dijit.form.RadioButton' name='Project Info' id='radioThree' value='Project_Info' checked: 'true'/>" + "<label for='radioOne'>Project Info</label><br />"
});
radioButtonPane.set('content',radioOne);
```

And its done what I needed. Thank you **h4b0**